# javascript passing variable to a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem getting the value of 'name' displayed with the following:

```
   for (var name in array) {
        var hoverIn = function() {
                  alert(name);
        };

        var hoverOut = function() {
        };

        thing.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

   }
```

What I get is an alert window with the last value of name. Clearly I am doing something wrong and I suspect it's a simple fix. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's closure problem, `name`, after that iteration is the last `name` in `array`, and callback for hovers isn't executed right away when the iteration happens, thus when the hover function is actually executed, `name` will always be the last in `array`.

You need to use IEFE (Immediately executed function expression):

```
   for (var name in array) {
        // pass in name to the anonymous function, and immediately
        // executes it to retain name when the particular iteration happens
        var hoverIn = (function(name) {
             return function() {
                  alert(name);
             }
        })(name); // if you notice, the pattern is (function(name) {})(name) 
                  // the first () creates an anonymous function, the (name) 
                  // executes it, effectively passing name to the anon fn

        var hoverOut = (function(name) {
            // same pattern if you need to re-use name inside here, otherwise just
            // function() { } should suffice
        })(name);

        thing.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

   }
```

To avoid duplicates of `(function() { })()` (which honestly is getting tiring to look at), you could also, as @pimvdb pointed out, wrap the whole body in a closure:

```
   for (var name in array) {
        (function(name) {
           var hoverIn = function() {
               alert(name);
           }

           var hoverOut = function() {
           }

           thing.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
        })(name); // closure of for loop body

   }
```

Comment: You should not pass var to the function! Why do you create a copy of the name?

Comment: As a side note, one could also just wrap the whole `for` loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable inside the loop

```
var thisName = name;
```

and then use that in your function

```
alert(thisName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of dealing with this problem.

The first thing to know is that scope only happens at function level, not within loops in javascript.
If you set a variable within a function from an outside source and don't execute it right away,the variable will be changed over the course of your loop.

You can solve this  by closing other the variable:

```
var names = ["john","paul","george","ringo"];
var store = {};

//this function receives the data as a parameter
//so it will be a safe copy.

function createFunc(name){
     //just return a function that will alert the name.
    return function(){
       alert(name);
    }
}
for (var i in names) {

        var hoverIn = createFunc(names[i]);

        store[names[i]]=hoverIn;

}
store["john"]();
```

The other way is to create an anonymous function that executes right away 
within the loop:

```
var names = ["john","paul","george","ringo"];
var store = {};

for (var i in names) {
   //the function receives the i as a parameter
   //and executes, so n is a safe copy of i
  (function(n){

    var hoverIn = function(){
        alert(names[n]);
    }

    store[names[n]]=hoverIn;

  })(i);

}
store["john"]();
```

Everything is a problem related to closure. 
Look at wikipedia for more info.

Answer (score -2):

You should create closure:

```
 for (var name in array) {
        var hoverIn = (function() {
              return function() {
                  alert(name);
              };
        }());

        var hoverOut = function() {
        };

        thing.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
   }
```

Comment: That would not fix anything: he already had a closure over var name. A closure closes over variables, not values. That's why it did not work.

Comment: Here, `name` still refers to the one of the `for` loop, so it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel You dont understand what closure means=) Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yHSpg/. And then will have realized that was wrong!

Comment: @Serjio: No, you're not fully understanding it. Try the infamous `setTimeout` example of your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yHSpg/1/.

Comment: @pimvdb but there is no `setTimeout` in question=)

Comment: @Serjio: The point is the same: `name` will not be accessed directly like your `alert` does, but some time later when `name` will be the last name.

Comment: @pimvdb No this is a bit different tasks. You should not copy variable you can. It's my opinion

Comment: I respect your opinion but it simply does not work. Here's a demo of your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Fym87/. It alerts `1` twice, not `0` and `1`.